# Why can't I change address of a pointer of type `const int *` when passed as function argument?

Tags: c++, pointers, parameter-passing, const-pointer

As far as I know, `const int *` implies that I can change the pointer but not the data, `int * const` says that I can't change the pointer address but I can change the data, and `const int * const` states that I can't change any of them.

However, I can't change a address of a pointer defined with the type `const int *`. Here is my example code:

```
void Func(const int * pInt)
{
    static int Int = 0;
    pInt = &Int;
    Int++;
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{
    int Dummy = 0;
    const int * pInt = &Dummy;
    //const int * pInt = nullptr;   // Gives error when I try to pass it to Func().
    std::cout << pInt << '\t' << *pInt << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-------------------" << std::endl;
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        Func(pInt);     // Set the pointer to the internal variable. (But, it doesn't set it!)
        std::cout << pInt << '\t' << *pInt << std::endl;
    }
     return 0;
}
```

Code output:

```
00D2F9C4        0
-------------------
00D2F9C4        0
00D2F9C4        0
00D2F9C4        0
00D2F9C4        0
00D2F9C4        0
```

I would expect the address of `pInt` to change to point to the internal variable inside the `Func()` function after calling `Func()` for at least once. But it doesn't. I keeps pointing at the `Dummy` variable.

What is happening here? Why don't I get the result I expect?

*(IDE: Visual Studio 2015 Community Version)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't see the change at the call site because you are passing the pointer by value. Modifying it inside `Func` will just change the local copy, not the pointer passed in.

If you want to modify the pointer and have the changes visible outside, pass it by reference:

```
void Func(const int *& pInt)
//                   ^
```